# Pass a username/password when accessing a folder via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, credentials, fso

I have a script that is meant to retrieve some files from a users old profile on a server and copy it to there new one, but the users do not have access rights for the folders/files in question when connecting through the server.

Is there a way passing a username/password with the following functions? Thanks.

```
objFSO.FolderExists(folder_path)
objFSO.CopyFolder(folder_path)
objFSO.CopyFile(folder_path)
```

Comment: VBA is visual basic for applications, the code used in the Microsoft Office family of applications. Are you using VBA or VBScript?

Comment: Apologies, it is VBS. However, the question has been seccessfully answered below, but thanks for you time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to map the share to a driveletter first, then

```
persistent = false
set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "driveletter:", "\\server\sharename", persistent, "username", "password"
```

Then use the normal filesystemobject to do the copying, using the driveletter or not.
Once authenticated this way it's possible to do other operations with these credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Required a bit of a re-wirte, but it was the way I needed to go. Many thanks.