# Log on as local administrator in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I have what should be a very simple script.  I have a series of 6 PCs that I need to check the existence of a file and report back.  Where the difficulty lies is that these devices are not part of AD and are part of a work group.  From windows explorer using **C$** I'm prompted to log on as a local administrator on the remote PC.  How can I perform the same logon and automate the process using the script below?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i = 1 To 6
If objFSO.FileExists("\\10.4.55." & i & "\c$\Program Files\X-1 Technologies\offline.fla") Then
    Wscript.Echo "Reg:" & i & " Off-Line."
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Reg:" & i & " On-Line."
End If
Next
```

Thanks, Lloyd

Comment: This might seem like extra work but if its only for 6 connections you could map a drive and dissolve it once done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831515/pass-a-username-password-when-accessing-a-folder-via-vbscript

Comment: I did consider that but this code is just a base for an expanded code set that will reach out to about ~115 groups of 6 PCs.  Speed of execution is important.   Lloyd

Comment: In that case I'd recommend switching to PowerShell. The `Get-Item` cmdlet supports passing explicit credentials via the `-Credentials` parameter. PowerShell also allows you to run tasks in parallel as jobs whereas VBScript doesn't support parallelization.