# How can I specify credential for access to shared folder, using SSIS

Tags: ssis

How can I specify credential for access to shared folder, using SSIS.
Can I do this, like in SSRS-schedule, when I can use "Credentials used to access the file share" (User Name \ Password)
I have username/password for shared folder.
I need save file to shared folder, however ssis-user account have not access to shared folder.
And I can not set up user from shared folder as proxi-user for start SSIS-package.

Comment: check here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831515/pass-a-username-password-when-accessing-a-folder-via-vbscript

Comment: you have to provide shared path access to account from which SSIS package is getting  executed Or you can create network location using  "Map Network dive"  on the server and provide credentials and use this drive in package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies.
I checked, it really works. One solution - to provide shared path access to account from which SSIS package is getting executed; other solution - "Map Network dive".
Is it all possible solutions?